# Table row data delete on Action Sheet Delete Button Pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to delete a table row when action sheet delete button pressed then I write a code like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UIActionSheet *action=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are You Sure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
        [action showInView:self.view];
    }
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    NSString *buttontitle=[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttontitle isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
    {
        [self.map removeObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
        //tableView is global object of your table view.
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    }
```

But Error is 'Undeclare identifier indexpath'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because here your indexPath variable is local to your method so you can not not access it into another method.

For this either you should make a global variable and save this index path in that variable and then access it any where you want.

Or set the tag to your action sheet and then access it.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UIActionSheet *action=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are You Sure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
        //set the index path as tag to action sheet.
        action.tag = indexPath.row;
        [action showInView:self.view];
    }
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    NSString *buttontitle=[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttontitle isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
    {
        //access that tag here.
        [self.map removeObjectAtIndex:action.tag];
        //here your tableView is global variable
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    }
```

Comment: You can also check inside action sheet tag that.if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //access that tag here.
        [self.map removeObjectAtIndex:action.tag];;
        [UITableView reloadData];
    } instead of title.

Comment: But then no known class method for selector 'reload data' is not found error is occur @IDeveloper

Comment: Because the reloadData is a object type method not a class type for this you need to make the table object global so that you can access it here. I had updated my answer check it again.

Comment: @AshishGabani sorry mistakenly I have updated you question instead of my answer please ignore it. Now check the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

You don't have the index path of the row you want to delete. You either have to get it from the table view  or save the index path passed by

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and reuse it in the action sheet callback.

Altogether, your approach does not seem to take advantage of the API. the UITableViewDelegate has methods that allow the user to see the "Delete" button and press or cancel it. I would suggest you check those out so that your app works and feels like other iOS apps.

```
tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:

tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:

tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:
```